# Add names to a Word Document and save it with that name (from CSV file)

Tags: excel, csv, ms-word, ms-office

This might be a tricky question, but let's see if anyone can help me out here.

I have 700 files to create. I already have the design, as I add it to a background image and I have a place in the .docx file to add the name.

I also have the names on a CSV file.

Is there any way to batch create (copy from the "template") the files and add the name over the document based on the CSV data I have?

PS: using Office 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Word's built-in mailmerge tools to generate a single document with a separate 'letter' for each of your 700 records. See: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-mail-merge-to-create-and-send-bulk-mail-labels-and-envelopes-f488ed5b-b849-4c11-9cff-932c49474705

Alternatively, if you need a separate document for each record, see *Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at:

http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

or:

http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/163017-Word-Mailmerge-Tips-amp-Tricks

Comment: Thank you sir, that worked! :) I mark your reply as correct. Sorry for the delay.